# Show only records where an array of objects exists for logged in user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Users can add multiple products and multiple users can request that product. When a user logs in, I want to show only products that have requests.

I tried this which is supposed to firstly find products for the userId which is currently logged in and WHERE the `'requests'` array exists.

```
Product.find({userId: req.user._id}).where('requests').exists(true)
```

But this is showing me ALL products, even ones without requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use plain MongoDB query syntax and [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator and `$ne` to filter out empty arrays:

```
Product.find({userId: req.user._id, requests: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is still showing me the product with an empty array though. If there is an empty array, that record should not show up. 'requests' is an array of objects

Comment: @user8463989 modified my answer, you can try once again

Comment: that seems to be good! And is it valid mongoose syntax though as I think you said that it was for mongo DB?

Comment: @user8463989 it's MongoDB way of querying but works fine in Mongoose as well

Comment: Okay, cool. Pushing my luck here but is it possible to get a count of the number of records in the array or should I rather ask that as a new question? I tried using $sum but that can't be used with an array it would seem.

Comment: You can take a look at `$size` operator, sample answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142110/mongodb-how-do-i-query-for-the-number-of-elements-in-an-array-of-documents-dict/49145067#49145067

Comment: thank you. Tried this but says I can't use total with array: `Product.find({userId: req.user._id, requests: { $exists: true, $ne: [], total: {$size:  "$requests" } }})`

Comment: sorry, last post, promise! This tells me that $size needs a number. `Product.find({userId: req.user._id, requests: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }, total: {$size:  "$requests" }})`

Comment: @user8463989 you need to use aggregate like in that example and put your condition into `$match` stage

Comment: ah! I just looked at the $size bit of the code. Thanks again!